# Bing Maps Get Route Distance v8

Tags: bing-maps

I am updating the maps from 6 to 8.
How to get a route distance in bing v8 maps? The route has 4 waypoints.

Back on 6 was calculating the routelegs.

Is there a request that presents the route distance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the directions module in V8 and add a directionsUpdated event. In the event handler you can get the distance from the route summary. Here is an example: http://bingmapsv8samples.azurewebsites.net/#Directions_Events (source code button in top right corner).

If you only want distance and don't want to render the route, you might want to consider using the REST routing service. It would likely be slightly faster.